# business processes Framework (Xamarin or ReactJS)

Tags: android, reactjs, xamarin, process

maybe someone can help me.  In near future i'm going to develop a business processes application like this :

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.semture.cubetto

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.showgen.processcraft

Now i would like to know if there are some already existing Frameworks or projects for that. I just want play arount with that subject to get a feeling how it works and what i have to do. I'm planing to make it available for Android (highest priority) and Web (Ios and windows arent so important right now).

So my first question is. Are there any Frameworks, libs, project availbe for something like that?

I've already searched for some frameworks but without no success...

And the other question would be what Tool or language should i use ?

Currently i'm working with Visual Studios 2015 Xamarin (xml & C# based language). We all know that i can make crossplattform apps with xamarin. But some minutes ago i've heard that there is a language/Framework named React.JS, that is also for android ios and web apps.

Now my second question:

which one should i work with ? Xamarin or React.Js ? Which one would better fit to my project and what are the main differences ?

I hope someone could answer that :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This really comes down to personal preference and what you are trying to accomplish. If you are a C# developer, then Xamarin might be your best bet for android. With using ReactNative, it will be a little easier to create your web app from since it uses React. If you are trying to have a native feel for the android app, you will still have to know some core android development for both platforms. If you aren't super worried about the look, feel, and performance of it being native, then you can look into ionic which is built on top of Angular, and this you can use as a web application as well as build it for android.

Comment: Hmmm ok Thanks and how about existing frameworks ? Do you know something?

Comment: is there any existing code on git or so for that kind of apps. Or should i develop it from scratch ? I'm searching something like a bussiness tool framework or so

Comment: I don't know anything about xamarin, however there are lots of React Native and Ionic examples out there. I know there are even ionic templates out there that you can purchase. They also both have a CLI that will scaffold out an app for you. I would recommend starting from mostly scratch, because you won't find something that does exactly what you're looking for and it will take longer for you to try to change it than write it yourself...plus you won't learn as much that way.